# Неверное отображение мобильного меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Разрабатываю меню для сайта, но есть небольшая проблемка: когда нажимаешь на пункт меню, он разворачивает подпункты следующего пункта, а не своего.

```css
#nav_container {
    background-color: #F0F1F2;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.navigation {
    max-width: 1168px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.navigation > ul {
    display: flex;
}

.navigation > ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F0F1F2;
    padding: 15px;
}

.navigation li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.navigation li > ul li {
    border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
}

.navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.navigation [type="checkbox"],
.navigation label.toggleSubmenu {
    display: none;
}

.navigation label.toggleMenu {
    background: #F0F1F2;
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation label.toggleMenu .fa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    left: 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .navigation {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .navigation ul {
        display: none;
    }

    .navigation label.toggleMenu {
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation li:hover > ul {
        display: none;
    }

    input.toggleMenu:checked ~ ul,
    input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ ul {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .navigation label.toggleSubmenu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 13%;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }

    input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ a {
        background: #F0F1F2;
    }  

}
```

```html
<div id="nav_container">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="menu" class="toggleMenu">
                    <label for="menu" class="toggleMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Меню</label>
                    <ul class="top_menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" class="toggleSubmenu" id="sub_m1">
                            <a href="#">О нас</a>
                            <label for="sub_m1" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Комплаенс-политика</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" class="toggleSubmenu" id="sub_m2">
                            <a href="#">Грузовые автомобили</a>
                            <label for="sub_m2" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Модельный ряд MAN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Магистральные перевозки</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Строительство</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Развозные перевозки</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Седельные тягачи MAN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Самосвалы MAN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Спецтехника MAN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Системы безопасности</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Автобусы</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Модельный ряд</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Туристические автобусы</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Междугородные автобусы MAN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Лизинг</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Лизинг</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                        </ul></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Ремонт грузовиков MAN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Виды услуг</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Кузовной ремонт</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Стоимость услуг</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mobile24</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Сервисные контракты</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Эвакуатор</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Запасные части</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Обзор</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Оптовая продажа запчастей</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле существует множество способов решения. Я предложу вам несколько пересмотреть изначальную структуру, хотя на самом деле принципиальной разницы, конечно же, нет.

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #F0F1F2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.navigation>label {
  display: none;
}

.navigation>input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.navigation>ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navigation>ul>li>input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.navigation>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 15px 0 0 -15px;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation>ul>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #F0F1F2;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .navigation>ul>li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation label {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .navigation>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation ul {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navigation>ul>li {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navigation>ul>li>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <label for="top_menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Меню
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="top_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><label><a href="#">Главная</a></label></li>
    <li>
      <label for="submenu_1">
        <i class="fa"></i><a href="#">О нас</a>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="submenu_1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Комплаенс-политика</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="submenu_2">
        <i class="fa"></i><a href="#">Грузовые автомобили</a>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="submenu_2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Модельный ряд MAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Магистральные перевозки</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Строительство</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Развозные перевозки</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Седельные тягачи MAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Самосвалы MAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Спецтехника MAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Системы безопасности</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="submenu_3">
        <i class="fa"></i><a href="#">Автобусы</a>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="submenu_3">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Модельный ряд</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Туристические автобусы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Междугородные автобусы MAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="submenu_4">
        <i class="fa"></i><a href="#">Лизинг</a>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="submenu_4">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Лизинг</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="submenu_5">
        <i class="fa"></i><a href="#">Услуги</a>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="submenu_5">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ремонт грузовиков MAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Виды услуг</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Кузовной ремонт</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Стоимость услуг</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mobile24</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Сервисные контракты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Эвакуатор</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="submenu_6">
        <i class="fa"></i><a href="#">Запасные части</a>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="submenu_6">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Обзор</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Оптовая продажа запчастей</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><label><a href="#">Контакты</a></label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с этим кодом.

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Все, я разобрался. В медиа запросе, нужно было подстроить ширину

```css
.navigation label.toggleSubmenu {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
```

и переместить label выше ссылки

```html
<label for="sub_m1" class="toggleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" class="toggleSubmenu" id="sub_m1">
<a href="#">О нас</a>
```

тогда сабменю не залезает на все остальные пункты